# json and encode strings

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have this list of strings..

```
mylist = [u"čeština", u"maďarština", u"francouština"]
```

I need to dump it into a file, I am using JSON for that

```
text = json.dumps(mylist)
FILE = open("file.txt", 'w')
FILE.write(text)
FILE.close()
```

But when I open the file in editor(with utf-8) I see

```
["\u010de\u0161tina", "ma\u010far\u0161tina", "francou\u0161tina"]
```

When I read the list from the file, I get right values.
But this file should be displayed also user-friedly, also I expect..

```
["čeština", "maďarština", "francouština"]
```

or at least

```
[u"čeština", u"maďarština", u"francouština"]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable name, since it is a reserved keyword in python.

Comment: maybe You should consider to use yaml

Comment: edited: list -> mylist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `json.dumps([u"čeština", u"maďarština", u"francouština"])` you will get the string `'["\\u010de\u0161tina", "ma\\u010far\u0161tina", "francou\\u0161tina"]'` (using valid Python string literal form).  The `\u` escapes are how Unicode is represented in JSON, and Python's JSON module will convert all non-ascii characters to Unicode escapes by default.  You can disable this behavior by using `ensure_ascii=False` in the `json.dumps()` arguments.

Here are a few examples, first the default behavior:

```
>>> json.dumps(lst)
'["\\u010de\\u0161tina", "ma\\u010far\\u0161tina", "francou\\u0161tina"]'
>>> print json.dumps(lst)
["\u010de\u0161tina", "ma\u010far\u0161tina", "francou\u0161tina"]
```

And with `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
>>> json.dumps(lst, ensure_ascii=False)
u'["\u010de\u0161tina", "ma\u010far\u0161tina", "francou\u0161tina"]'
>>> print json.dumps(lst, ensure_ascii=False)
["čeština", "maďarština", "francouština"]
```

Now to make sure you are writing this Unicode string using utf-8 you can use the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module:

```
import codecs, json
lst = [u"čeština", u"maďarština", u"francouština"]
json.dump(lst, codecs.open('file.txt', 'w', 'utf-8'), ensure_ascii=False)
```

Note that I also used `json.dump()` which writes directly to a file instead of `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 4):

`u"čeština` is not valid JSON.  As far as I know, you can't have multibyte characters in JSON strings either (i.e. it is also invalid), but I can't back that up.

`["\u010de\u0161tina"]` is valid JSON.  When it is parsed the UTF-8 characters can be decoded from the `\u` parts.  For some peace of mind, open your browsers console, type `"\u010de\u0161tina"` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and see the string that is printed.